# Network not available showing for android app jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

> I am creating jmeter load test script for native android app. So i set manual proxy for WIFI in my android device. PORT set 8080 for both device and jmeter. When i started recoding then its recording device browser actions but not recording native app action. Its showing error like "Internet not available". I have installed jmeter certificate too in the device. So how i can create jmeter script for native android app?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this gonna help you but you can look into it once, i face similar issue while recording from Mozilla by adding proxy manually. After i change the port number which i kept same with Jmeter, it started recording. Its the port as per my knowledge and change it to more of less known port from 8080 to 8089 in both Jmeter n in ur Android mobile.

Check below link, hope it helps:

> [load-testing-mobile-apps-made-easy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-mobile-apps-made-easy)